# TPM (Trusted Platform Module) vs. TEE (Trusted Execution Environment) - can credentials be *stored* on both?

Tags: security, encryption, hardware, mobile-data, tee

TPM is physically *isolated* from the rest of the system (i.e. it is a standalone chip on the mainboard), while TEE is a *secure area* of the main CPU.

The key function of both TPM and TEE is to do cryptographic calculations, but can they also **store** credentials/keys used in these calculations?

I know SE (Secure Element - also a standalone chip) is used exactly for storage purposes, but only 30% of modern smartphones have SE integrated (and mostly expensive models). So how is the credential **storage** task solved in TPM/TEE scenarios?

Thank you!

Comment: Android phones have as far as I know no TPM.

Comment: TEE doesn't have its own storage. Even its firmware is loaded from the `/vendor` partition. Its storage is separately provisioned by the manufacturer.

Comment: @defalt Thank you for this comment! Do I understand right, that TEE uses storage within CPU itself (_secure_ part of which TEE is), or is it rather that TEE utilizes *external* built-in memory modules, which every mobile has (e.g., 32/64/128Gb)?

Comment: Yes, an on-die secure element is provisioned. E.g. [Qualcomm SPU](https://www.xda-developers.com/qualcomm-snapdragon-855-secure-processing-unit-eal4/).

Comment: Also, [see this diagram](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FXspMfIaAAAv96N?format=png&name=small). It shows secure element as storage for ARM TrustZone based integrated TEEs.

Comment: @defalt Well, the diagram doesn't _clearly_ show that TEE is an **integral** part of Cortex, while it is, but it's OK - I know that. :) Secure Element (aka SE) is a _standalone_ thing which serves as a key storage (mainly). Do I understand you right that the storage capacity we see in mobile phone specs (32/64/128Gb) is an **SE element**, not just a regular memory chip? In other words - _all_ mobile phones have SE on board. I strongly doubt that...

Comment: @defalt And coming back to my previous question: I didn't clearly understand which memory does TEE finally utilize in its work? AFAIK, it either doesn't have _its own_ memory allocated within **trusted** SPU area, or this memory capacity is _very_ limited. I know that there are TEE + SE conjunctions, but what if there's *no* SE on board: does TEE use only those limited memory capacities within secure area (= itself) or does it use external resources, like those huge 54/128Gb memory storages?

Comment: ARM Trustzone uses system memory and CPU. The storage for the TEE is integrated by the manufacturer. They don't need to embed a whole SE just for the storage. The underlying storage that SE uses can be manufactured & integratred with TEE independently.

Comment: @defalt Sure, SE is more than just a storage, so embedding it to store keys only is probably not the best idea, specifically if TEE is already on board. By the way, are you familiar with how access to SE is organized on the software level? AFAIK, Android StrongBox is used (AFAIK - as a part of Keystore functionality) to access **basic** SE functions, while Open Mobile API (OMAPI) is used for *direct* (hence - **more sofisticated**) communication with SE. Is that so?

Comment: SE is connected with SPI bus channel. Android has Keystore API that communicates with the **Hardware Abstraction Layer** in android vendor layer that communicates with the driver that communicates with the SE.

Comment: ... which means OMAPI [link](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/open-mobile-api) has **no** advantages over Keystore in capabilities to access SE and manage its functions?

Comment: This is recently added in android 13 userspace ABI to make use of OMAPI.

Comment: Got it: OMAPI is now **integral** part of Android (same as Keystore *already* was). Thank you! Will appreciate if you can share a link to read more about this, I mean if you have it at hand of course. Many thanks for your patience and invaluable help!